# Work 2.8.0 + Hilt not initializing workers

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

There's a bunch of questions like this, but I haven't found a solution that helps me.

app/build.gradle

```
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0'

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44"
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            tools:node="remove">
        </provider>
```

Application

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

// other stuff

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

One of my workers

```
@HiltWorker
class Some @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val someRepository: SomeRepository,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {
}
```

I get work manager instance with `WorkManager.getInstance(context)`

Worker is not initialized with exception

```
Could not instantiate some.path.SomeWorker
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: some.path.SomeWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2201)
at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:145)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-02-12 22:48:56.505 22235-22316 WM-WorkerWrapper
E  Could not create Worker some.path.SomeWorker
```

If I leave only context and worker params in the constructor, than it works fine

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment; I had my dependencies all mixed up. It looks like you might just be missing `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'` as listed on the page with [the requirements for using Hilt with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager). With everything else correct, removing only that results in exactly the described behavior.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot, this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after 2 days of investigating the problem was with the initialization of the library OneSignal (One Signal SDK version 4.8.6), so I had to downgrade to 4.8.4 and it worked. For further info

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/1748