# Android Worker (2.8.1) with Hilt and constructor params throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, kotlin, worker

I've read all related questions and discussions ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75555455/work-2-8-0-hilt-not-initializing-workers), [example2](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2690)) and nothing seems to fix my problem. This is in desperation, if anyone can notice what am I doing wrong?

Here's my build.gradle configuration:

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44.2'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
kapt 'com.squareup.inject:assisted-inject-annotations-dagger2:0.6.0'
implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:2.9.0-alpha01"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
```

on project level:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44.2'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.6.0-alpha07"
}
```

My Worker implmentation:

```
@HiltWorker
class ImageUploadWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
@Assisted val appContext: Context,
@Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
private val myRepositoryImpl: MyRepositoryImpl) 
:CoroutineWorker(appContext,workerParams) {
 
 
}
```

Application level:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var imageUploadWorkerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration = Configuration.Builder()
    .setWorkerFactory(imageUploadWorkerFactory)
    .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
    .build()

}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

RESULT:
[image]

NOTE: if I remove `private val myRepositoryImpl: MyRepositoryImpl` from `ImageUploadWorker`, the initialization error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

- The declared manifest `<provider/>` is only communicated with the **App Startup**. You have not declared the WorkManager Configuration `<provider/>` in the `AnidroidManifest.xml`. This is the solution for you.

```xml
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

- So if you want to use **App startup** with **WorkManager Configuration** you can do this

```xml
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

> Also if you have custom androidx.startup class like this?

```kotlin
// You can use whatever you want as the Type::class I used `Unit`
class BaseInitializer : Initializer<Unit> {

    override fun create(context: Context) {
        // Do anything that you want
    }

    override fun dependencies(): MutableList<Class<out Initializer<*>>> = mutableListOf()
}
```

- You can declare the `<provider/>` if you used the above method you have to update the `AnidroidManifest.xml` like this.

```xml
        <!-- android.startup -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <!-- This is custom initializer for app startup -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="PATH_TO_YOUR_INITIALIZER_CLASS"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <!-- This is for work manager initializer -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>
```

- Replace the `PATH_TO_YOUR_INITIALIZER_CLASS` with the custom initializer classpath that have you created above **BaseInitializer**

> example :- ${applicationId}.initializer.BaseInitializer

###### Refer to this link for further information,

[App Startup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup)

[Custom WorkManager Configuration and Initialization](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration#on-demand)

###### I think this is the solution to your problem. You can try And I hope you understood

**Sorry for late response**

-Thank you.